# How to use awk to extract just the band name from the output of tageditor?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to organize my Music better m4a, mp3, etc. Since the files are tagged I thought I could make a script to read the file and pull the album and artist info from the file then mv the file in the proper folder. I also wanted to learn some AWK in the process.

I started with:

```
for file in *.m4a; do
    tageditor get artist -f "$file" | awk '/Artist/{ print }'
    done
```

Output:

```
Artist            Periphery
Artist            Meshuggah, Tomas Haake, Marten Hagström, Fredrik Thordendal,
Artist            Varials, Bryan Garris
Artist            Cannibal Corpse
Artist            Lamb of God
Artist            Ingested
Artist            Linkin Park
Artist            Car Bomb
Artist            Whitechapel
Artist            Divine Destruction
Artist            Ingested, Sean Hynes, Sam Yates, Jason Evans, Lyn Jeffs
```

Then:

```
for file in *.m4a; do
    tageditor get artist -f "$file" | awk '/Artist/{ print $2 }'
    done
```

Output:

```
Periphery
Angelmaker,
Meshuggah,
Varials,
Cannibal
Lamb
Ingested
Linkin
Car
Whitechapel
Divine
Ingested,
```

I am still trying to understand how awk works so I reworked my code

for file in ./*.m4a; do
info=$(tageditor get artist album -f "${file}")
prt1=$(echo "$info" | awk 'sub(/^.{22}/,"")')
prt2=$(echo "$prt1" | awk 'NR>2' )
art="$prt2"
albm=$(echo "$prt2" | awk 'NR==1' ) band=$(echo "$art" | awk 'NR==2' )
echo "$info"
echo
echo "$prt1"
echo
echo "$prt2"
echo
echo "$albm"    #ALBUM
echo
echo "$band"    #ARTIST
echo

I got:
Tag information for "./Do Not Look Down.m4a":

- MP4/iTunes tag
  Album             Koloss
  Artist            Meshuggah, Tomas Haake, Marten Hagström, Fredrik Thordendal, Tomas Haake

/Do Not Look Down.m4a":
[0m
Koloss
Meshuggah, Tomas Haake, Marten Hagström, Fredrik Thordendal, Tomas Haake

Koloss
Meshuggah, Tomas Haake, Marten Hagström, Fredrik Thordendal, Tomas Haake

Koloss

Meshuggah, Tomas Haake, Marten Hagström, Fredrik Thordendal, Tomas Haake

How can I use awk to delete everything after the , in the last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sub()` function to remove unwanted part from the beginning of each line:

```
for file in ./*.m4a; do
    tageditor get artist -f "$file" | awk 'sub(/^Artist */, "")'
done
```

I'm also thinking the output of the `tageditor` command is Tab delimited output; if that was, you can restrict awk's default whitespace (Tabs/SPCs) seperators into Tab character only then print the second column of it:

```
for file in ./*.m4a; do
    tageditor get artist -f "$file" | awk -F'\t' '/^Artist/{ print $2 }'
done
```

also I found that `tageditor` command can read multiple files by itself, so you can do as following too.

```
tageditor get artist -f /path/to/*.m4a | awk -F'\t' '/^Artist/{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 9):

[exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) is command-line tool (written in perl) that can do what you want (including moving and renaming files based on metadata) from from the shell command-line or shell script.

Don't be fooled by the "EXIF" in the name, it can read and write the metadata from lots of different file types, not just EXIF data - from images and audio and video formats to documents such as microsoft office formats like docx and xls, open office formats, PDFs, and more.

See the man page for details.

---

If you still want to write your own rather than use `exiftool`, then read on:

I recommend using `perl` for a task like this because it has several library modules which can read (and write) metadata from various file formats.

[Image::ExifTool](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::ExifTool) is one such library.   It was, and still is, developed to support both the `exiftool` program and people who wanted to write their own specialised tools.

If you're using Debian, you can install both the `Image::Exiftool` library and the command-line `exiftool` mentioned above with `sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl`.  It has almost certainly been packaged for other distros (e.g. on Centos, the package is called `perl-Image-ExifTool`).

While I suggest `Image::Exiftool` because it can work with lots of different kinds of files (so you get maximum benefit from the effort you put into learning it), it is not the only perl library for this.  There are many others, including [MP4::Info](https://metacpan.org/pod/MP4::Info) and [Audio::Scan](https://metacpan.org/release/Audio-Scan).  These two are packaged as `libmp4-info-perl` and `libaudio-scan-perl` on debian.

Perl can also create directories and rename files etc and, unlike shell, won't have any issues with quoting, whitespace or shell metacharacters in filenames and variables.  You've already run into some of these with your shell and awk code and it will be a very significant problem with both the long filenames common with media files and the metadata within them. It will be a **lot** easier to write this in `perl` than in either shell or `awk`, and a lot less error-prone to write it in any language other than shell.

`perl`, like `awk`, was written to be part of the unix environment - it's often referred to as a "swiss-army chainsaw" combining the capabilities of all the usual unix tools (`grep`, `sed`, `tr`, `awk`, `cut`, etc etc) into one language.

If you have even basic familiarity with C-like syntax, perl is easy enough to learn, with a mixed procedural and optional object-oriented programming style.  [Learn Perl Now](https://perl-begin.org/learn/) is a good place to start, with lots of info about perl and links to most of the important perl-related sites.  Their ["Perl for Newbies" Online Tutorial](https://perl-begin.org/tutorials/perl-for-newbies/) is excellent.

Much of what you learn for perl will be re-usable in `awk` (within the context of the "CONDITION {ACTION}" rule style of awk, the language is also C-like), as well as `grep` and `sed` (same as in sed, regular expressions are operators like + and - in perl, not function calls.  e.g. `s/search/replace/` rather than something like `re.sub(search,replace,string)`, and other unix tools.

---

Python would also be a pretty good choice because it also has library modules for working with the metadata in files but is, IMO, more suited to writing "applications" rather than command-line "tools".  An object-oriented programming style is pretty much mandatory and (unlike almost every other language except Fortran) whitespace & indentation is both inflexible and syntactically significant (i.e. the code will behave differently if the indentation is not right, making it difficult to spot some kinds of errors). Aside from general programming principles and practices, what you learn from python will be less immediately re-usable with other unix tools.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do (using `cat file` in place of `tageditor...` which I don't have)?

```
$ cat file | awk 'sub(/^Artist[[:space:]]+/,""){sub(/,.*/,""); print}'
Periphery
Meshuggah
Varials
Cannibal Corpse
Lamb of God
Ingested
Linkin Park
Car Bomb
Whitechapel
Divine Destruction
Ingested
```

Don't use `/Artist/` unanchored as that will match anywhere on the line, not just when `Artist` is the first string:

```
$ printf 'Foo\tBob The Artist\nArtist\tLamb of God\nArtistically\tIs how we do it\n'
Foo     Bob The Artist
Artist  Lamb of God
Artistically    Is how we do it

$ printf 'Foo\tBob The Artist\nArtist\tLamb of God\nArtistically\tIs how we do it\n' |
    awk '/Artist/'
Foo     Bob The Artist
Artist  Lamb of God
Artistically    Is how we do it

$ printf 'Foo\tBob The Artist\nArtist\tLamb of God\nArtistically\tIs how we do it\n' |
    awk '/^Artist[[:space:]]/'
Artist  Lamb of God
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *.m4a; do
    tageditor get artist -f "$file" | sed -r "s/.* \s+//g"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude column 1

```
for file in *.m4a; do
    tageditor get artist -f "$file" | awk '/Artist/{$1=""}1'
done
```